# Java Constructors - Why is age returning as zero?

Tags: java, constructor

First time creating my own constructor.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Person {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your name");
        PersonDetails a = new PersonDetails(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter your age");
        PersonDetails b = new PersonDetails(input.nextInt());

        System.out.println("So your name is" + " " + a.getName() + " and you are" + " " + a.getAge());

    }
}
```

**PersonDetails class**

```
public class PersonDetails {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public PersonDetails(String initialName) {
        if(initialName.equals("Stephen")) {
            name = initialName;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Access denied");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public PersonDetails(int initialAge) { 
        if(initialAge >= 18) {
            age = initialAge;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You are a child");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

The output is:

**Please enter your name**

Stephen

**Enter your age**

19

So your name is Stephen and you are 0

When I input Stephen and then the number 19. Why is it zero?

Comment: because you are creating two seperate instances of your `PersonDetails` class. and your `PersonDetails` variable `b` holds the age.

Comment: Create a `setAge` and then set age of first instance -> `a.setAge(20)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created 2 instances of `PersonDetails`. The `a` instance only has the name set, the `b` instance only has the age set.

You could create a new constructor, taking the name and age as parameters:

```
  public PersonDetails(String initialName, int initialAge) {
    if (initialName.equals("Stephen")) {
      name = initialName;
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Access denied");
      System.exit(0);
    }

    if (initialAge >= 18) {
      age = initialAge;
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("You are a child");
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
```

Then, use your class as follows:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your name");
String name = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter your age");
Int age = input.nextInt();
PersonDetails a = new PersonDetails(name, age);

System.out.println("So your name is" + " " + a.getName() + " and you are" + " " + a.getAge());
```

I would also not recommend having `System.exit(0);` in the constructor of a class. It would be better to throw an exception in that case, possibly outside of the constructor (so do your validation somewhere else).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are creating **two** different objects , you have to use `b.getAge()`

```
private int age;
```

here `age` is initialized by zero that's why when you call `a.getAge()` you get `0` as a result

From [javaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a
>   reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default
>   will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such
>   default values, however, is generally considered bad programming
>   style.

Better Solution :

Create constructor that takes name and age

```
public PersonDetails(String name, int age) {
        if (name.equals("Stephen")) {
              this.name = initialName;
        }
        else {
              System.out.println("Access denied");
              System.exit(0);
        }

        if (age >= 18) {
              this.age = age;
        }
        else {
              System.out.println("You are a child");
              System.exit(0);
        }
}
```

And Create one object instead of two